# How to handle new_chat_members when a user joined to telegram group with telegram bot?

Tags: laravel, telegram-bot

I'm trying to send a message to user, who joined to a group, with my telegram bot. I add bot to the group and bot is admin in group. and I set the Group Privacy off. I get user with `new_chat_member` when user joined to group, but the message send to user infinitely. And the update which is for when a member join to group is pending.

```
 if(isset($arrayMessage['message'])) {
    if (isset($arrayMessage['message']['new_chat_member'])) {
        $text= "hello!";
        $url= "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token."/sendMessage?chat_id=".$chat_id."&text=".$text;
        file_get_contents($url);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you are using long polling for this answer. When using the `getUpdates` method, it will keep retrieving the existing unconfirmed updates until you confirm them by using the offset parameter.

See [enter link description here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#long-polling-gives-me-the-same-updates-again-and-again)

If you do not confirm the updates, you will keep receiving the same update, thus the infinite messages.